# Shortening a file name in a Magento output file

Tags: magento, xslt

First of all, please accept my apologies if I say stupid things in my post! I really don't understand this programming language and have only got so far through trial and error!

I am trying to output a Magento order in to a file, ready for upload to our POS.

Here is my template so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<files>
<file filename="%lastincrementid%.txt">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="sepstart" select="'&#34;'"/> <!-- &#34; field start seperator, including '' -->
<xsl:variable name="sepend" select="'&#34;,'"/> <!-- field end seperator, including '' -->

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="orders/order">
<xsl:for-each select="items/item">
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(sku)"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(qty)"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(price)"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(row_total)"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../../increment_id)"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />

<xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</file>
</files>
```

The format of %lastincrementid% is a 9 digit number such as 100007654.

The filename is currently set to be this 9 digit number BUT I want it to be only the last 4 digits, ie 7654.

Can anyone please be kind enough to show me how I go about it? I would be eternally grateful........ :-)

Comment: Apologies. I incorrectly said that I wanted to use increment_id rather than the %lastincrementid% that the filename is currently set to.

Comment: "I really don't understand this programming language and have only got so far through trial and error!" I'm not sure how literally you mean that, but I would highly recommend reading an introductory book on XSLT. It's not the kind of subject that works well with trail and error.

Comment: `%lastincrementid%` isn't actually any sort of XSLT construct. Additionally, I notice your XSLT stylesheet `xsl:stylesheet` is nested within a `file` element, which on its own would not make it valid XSLT. This suggests this might not actually be an XSLT question, but more a question about this "magneto" which you mention in comments in the given answer. It might be worth adding "magneto" as a tag, and giving a bit more detail about it in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Tim, will do :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`substring()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring)...

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(../../increment_id),6,4)"/>
```

**Edit** (complete guess at what is trying to be accomplished)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="sepstart" select="'&#34;'"/>
  <!-- &#34; field start seperator, including '' -->
  <xsl:variable name="sepend" select="'&#34;,'"/>
  <!-- field end seperator, including '' -->

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="id">%lastincrementid%</xsl:variable>
    <files>
      <file filename="{substring($id,6,4)}.txt">

        <xsl:for-each select="orders/order">
          <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepstart"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(sku)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepend"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepstart"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(qty)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepend"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepstart"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(price)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepend"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepstart"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(row_total)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepend"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepstart"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../../increment_id)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sepend"/>

            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </file>
    </files>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion. If I add that, I get the following error message: Error: Please repair the XSL Template of this profile. There was a problem processing the XSL Template:
 Line 3: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined

Comment: @RachelMoore - where are you trying to use the xsl:value-of? From the error it sounds like you're using it outside of the xsl:stylesheet. If you add an example of your XML, I can add a complete example.

Comment: I'm struggling, because I am not a programmer and really don't understand what I am doing! I am trying to output an order from Magento. The XSL template that I copied and pasted above gives the file name of 100007302.txt but I need it to be 7302.txt. Am I able to attach a file to this question because I have tested the template and can show you the output file?

Comment: @RachelMoore - I don't know anything about Magento, so anything additional you can add to your question would be helpful.

Comment: @RachelMoore - I also added a complete stylesheet. It's a total guess since I'm not familiar with Magento (I'm assuming `%lastincrementid%` works because of Magento.) Give it a try and see if that helps at all.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help me. I'm giving up for tonight because it is driving me mad! Perhaps a fresh set of eyes in teh morning may help :-)

Comment: @RachelMoore - Did you try the stylesheet from the question? If so, what were the results?

Comment: Hi Daniel,Yes, I tested it and got the following:

Comment: Error: Please repair the XSL Template of this profile. There was a problem processing the XSL Template:
 Line 1: Namespace prefix xsl on for-each is not defined
 Line 2: Namespace prefix xsl on for-each is not defined
 Line 3: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 4: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 5: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 6: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 7: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 8: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined

Comment: Line 9: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 10: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 11: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 12: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 13: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 14: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 15: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 16: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined
 Line 17: Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined

Comment: Line 19: Namespace prefix xsl on text is not defined
 Line 0: compilation error: element for-each
 Line 0: xsltParseStylesheetProcess : document is not a stylesheet